# Explanation of the multiplier of gaussian process kernels in sklearn document

Tags: regression, machine-learning, gaussian-process, kernel-trick, rbf-kernel

I have read the basic materials about gaussian process regression and understand its ideas.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/gaussian_process.html

However, when I look into the sklearn page, I have met some problems.

```
34.4**2 * RBF(length_scale=41.8)
+ 3.27**2 * RBF(length_scale=180) * ExpSineSquared(length_scale=1.44,
                                                   periodicity=1)
+ 0.446**2 * RationalQuadratic(alpha=17.7, length_scale=0.957)
+ 0.197**2 * RBF(length_scale=0.138) + WhiteKernel(noise_level=0.0336)
```

The code example in this page is given as above. My question is:
Why there is a squared multiplier before the kernel function? For example 34.4**2.
I understand the kernel function but don't understand why there is a squared multiplier.

And if there should be a squared multiplier, how should I choose its initial value?